# Multiple X-Swift.h files in one project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Can I have multiple header files importing different pieces of Swift code in a mainly Objective-C project?

I would like to not import absolutely *all* Swift code at once, only some parts of it, and also give these headers more descriptive names than `Project-Swift.h`.

Answer (score 0):

In Build Settings there is room for only one header to expose Swift code to Objective-C, it's the Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name.  You can specify a name different from the default if you want to.

If you you want to hide some Swift code from Objective-C, I can think of at least two ways:

- Use access control.  For example, use `fileprivate` or `private`, see
  https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AccessControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH41-ID3.
- If you want to hide a class from Objective-C, don't derive it from `NSObject`.